# Determination of the boundary of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ for the rank distance

Tags: general-topology

I consinder the set $ X=GL_n(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n,n} $ and the metric $$ d:\mathbb{R}^{n,n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n,n}\to \mathbb{R}, (A,B)\mapsto \text{rank}(A-B). $$

Now I tried to determine the boundary of $ X $. I use the following:

Suppose $ A\in \partial X $. So $ A $ is a boundary point which equivalent to:
$$ \forall \varepsilon >0: \quad \underbrace{B_{\varepsilon}(A)\cap X\neq \{\}}_{(i)} \quad \land \quad \underbrace {B_{\varepsilon}(A)\cap (\mathbb{R}^{n,n}\setminus X)\neq \{\}}_{(ii)}$$

(i) Consider $ M\in (B_{\varepsilon}(A)\cap X) $. It applies: $ 
\text{rank}(A-M)<\varepsilon $ and $ M\in X $ which means $ \text{rank}(M)=n $. So it applies that $ A=M $ and we get $ \text{rank}(A-M)=0<\varepsilon $. So $ A $ is invertible.

(ii) Now consider $ N\in (B_{\varepsilon}(A)\cap (\mathbb{R}^{n,n}\setminus X) $. It applies: $ 
\text{rank}(A-N)<\varepsilon $ and $ N\notin X $ which means $ \text{rank}(N)<n $. So it applies that $ A=N $ and we get $ \text{rank}(A-N)=0<\varepsilon $. So $ A $ is not invertible.

So (i) and (ii) is always wrong which means that $ A\in \partial X $ cannot exist. This implies $ \partial X=\{\} $.

Is that right?

Comment: For those (like me) who didn't know this distance, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2435621/305862)

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to be the most precise possible (in order in the present and the future to attract people). Do you agree ?

Comment: Yes. This title looks much better.

Comment: I did not check your solution but a better approach is to observe that this metric defines discrete topology.